# Corda node crashed after Artemis MessagingClient failed, "Artemis MessagingClient failed. Shutting down."

Tags: amqp, corda, activemq-artemis, amazon-efs

The following error occurs while running 2 nodes and a notary with CordaOSS4.3 (Amazon EFS is used for Artemis service of each node and notary).

・nodeA

```
[INFO ] 2021-03-24T01:53:33,526Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] engine.ConnectionStateMachine. - Transport Error TransportImpl [_connectionEndpoint=org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.ConnectionImpl@d8755f, org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.TransportImpl@720cb721] {localLegalName=O=nodeA, L=Local, C=JP, remoteLegalName=O=nodeB, L=Local, C=JP, serverMode=false}
[INFO ] 2021-03-24T01:53:33,526Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] engine.ConnectionStateMachine. - Error: connection aborted {localLegalName=O=nodeA, L=Local, C=JP, remoteLegalName=O=nodeB, L=Local, C=JP, serverMode=false}
[INFO ] 2021-03-24T01:53:33,527Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] netty.AMQPClient. - Disconnected from [NLBendpoint]:10005
[INFO ] 2021-03-24T01:53:33,527Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] netty.AMQPChannelHandler. - Closed client connection 828af8c0 from [NLBendpoint]:10005 to /xx.xx.x.xx:40438 {allowedRemoteLegalNames=O=nodeB, L=Local, C=JP, localCert=O=nodeA, L=Local, C=JP, remoteAddress=[NLBendpoint]:10005, remoteCert=O=nodeB, L=Local, C=JP, serverMode=false}
[INFO ] 2021-03-24T01:53:33,527Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] bridging.AMQPBridgeManager$AMQPBridge. - Bridge Disconnected {legalNames=O=nodeB, L=Local, C=JP, maxMessageSize=10485760, queueName=internal.peers.DLB29JcZp4kCP2aGGZKGkhw2X5RenndTjEK4xy48iT9643, targets=[NLBendpoint]:10005}

[WARN ] 2021-03-24T01:55:59,747Z [Thread-17936 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$5@2936f48a)] core.client. - AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119014: Did not receive data from /xxx.0.0.1:53166 within the 60,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
[WARN ] 2021-03-24T01:55:59,748Z [Thread-949 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] core.client. - AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119011: Did not receive data from server for org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnection@6eb6efd1[ID=e834052e, local= /127.0.0.1:53170, remote=localhost/127.0.0.1:10008] [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
[WARN ] 2021-03-24T01:55:59,751Z [Thread-948 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] core.client. - AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119011: Did not receive data from server for org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnection@505dd5b8[ID=f1885302, local= /127.0.0.1:53166, remote=localhost/127.0.0.1:10008] [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
[WARN ] 2021-03-24T01:55:59,751Z [Thread-950 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] core.client. - AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119011: Did not receive data from server for org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnection@57579387[ID=718e48b8, local= /127.0.0.1:53168, remote=localhost/127.0.0.1:10008] [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
[WARN ] 2021-03-24T01:55:59,774Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] netty.AMQPChannelHandler. - Closing channel due to nonrecoverable exception AMQ119014: Timed out after waiting 30,000 ms for response when sending packet 68 {allowedRemoteLegalNames=O=nodeB, L=Local, C=JP, localCert=O=nodeA, L=Local, C=JP, remoteAddress=[NLBendpoint]:10005, remoteCert=O=nodeB, L=Local, C=JP, serverMode=false}
[INFO ] 2021-03-24T01:55:59,775Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] netty.AMQPClient. - Retry connect to [NLBendpoint]:10005
[ERROR] 2021-03-24T01:55:59,779Z [Thread-612] errorAndTerminate. - ArtemisMessagingClient failed. Shutting down.
```

・notary

```
[INFO ] 2021-03-24T01:53:34,850Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-4] engine.ConnectionStateMachine. - Transport Error TransportImpl [_connectionEndpoint=org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.ConnectionImpl@1a1be565, org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.TransportImpl@1e6940e2] {localLegalName=O=Notary1, L=Local, C=JP, remoteLegalName=O=nodeA, L=Local, C=JP, serverMode=false}
[INFO ] 2021-03-24T01:53:34,850Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-4] engine.ConnectionStateMachine. - Error: connection aborted {localLegalName=O=Notary1, L=Local, C=JP, remoteLegalName=O=nodeA, L=Local, C=JP, serverMode=false}
[INFO ] 2021-03-24T01:53:34,851Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-4] netty.AMQPClient. - Disconnected from [NLBendpoint]:10008
[INFO ] 2021-03-24T01:53:34,851Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-4] netty.AMQPChannelHandler. - Closed client connection 9da3b393 from [NLBendpoint]:10008 to /xx.xx.x.xx:33438 {allowedRemoteLegalNames=O=nodeA, L=Local, C=JP, localCert=O=Notary1, L=Local, C=JP, remoteAddress=[NLBendpoint]:10008, remoteCert=O=nodeA, L=Local, C=JP, serverMode=false}
[INFO ] 2021-03-24T01:53:34,851Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-4] bridging.AMQPBridgeManager$AMQPBridge. - Bridge Disconnected {legalNames=O=nodeA, L=Local, C=JP, maxMessageSize=10485760, queueName=internal.peers.DLHVntq87Ai3vLSuQzG8BoKcc2napU6aU3NPVFwiF73322, targets=[NLBendpoint]:10008}
[INFO ] 2021-03-24T01:54:03,123Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-3] netty.AMQPClient. - Retry connect to [NLBendpoint]:10005
[WARN ] 2021-03-24T01:54:17,939Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-2] netty.AMQPChannelHandler. - SSL Handshake timed out {allowedRemoteLegalNames=O=nodeA, L=Local, C=JP, localCert=null, remoteAddress=[NLBendpoint]:10008, remoteCert=null, serverMode=false}
[ERROR] 2021-03-24T01:54:17,939Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-2] netty.AMQPChannelHandler. - Handshake failure handshake timed out {allowedRemoteLegalNames=O=nodeA, L=Local, C=JP, localCert=null, remoteAddress=[NLBendpoint]:10008, remoteCert=null, serverMode=false}

[INFO ] 2021-03-24T01:56:11,385Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-2] netty.AMQPClient. - Retry connect to [NLBendpoint]:10005
[INFO ] 2021-03-24T01:56:11,392Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-3] netty.AMQPClient. - Failed to connect to [NLBendpoint]:10005
[INFO ] 2021-03-24T01:56:13,393Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-4] netty.AMQPClient. - Retry connect to [NLBendpoint]:10005
[INFO ] 2021-03-24T01:56:13,398Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] netty.AMQPClient. - Failed to connect to [NLBendpoint]:10005
```

After these logs were output, the nodeA process was down. (The notary process is still running)
What could be the cause of this problem?
I suspect that the connection to the Artemis service has been lost as a result of some problem connecting to Amazon EFS because these are output in the OS log.

```
Mar 24 10:55:51 [serverName] stunnel: LOG5[4]: Connection reset: 1105153036 byte(s) sent to TLS, 839120060 byte(s) sent to socket
Mar 24 10:55:54 [serverName] stunnel: LOG5[5]: Service [efs] accepted connection from xxx.x.x.x:38710
Mar 24 10:55:54 [serverName] stunnel: LOG5[5]: s_connect: connected xx.xx.x.xx:2049
Mar 24 10:55:54 [serverName] stunnel: LOG5[5]: Service [efs] connected remote server from xx.xx.x.xx:51468
Mar 24 10:55:55 [serverName] stunnel: LOG5[5]: Certificate accepted at depth=0: CN=*.efs.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
Mar 24 10:55:55 [serverName] stunnel: LOG3[5]: transfer: s_poll_wait: TIMEOUTclose exceeded: closing
Mar 24 10:55:55 [serverName] stunnel: LOG5[5]: Connection closed: 0 byte(s) sent to TLS, 0 byte(s) sent to socket
Mar 24 10:55:55 [serverName] stunnel: LOG5[6]: Service [efs] accepted connection from xxx.x.x.x:38716
Mar 24 10:55:55 [serverName] stunnel: LOG5[6]: s_connect: connected xx.xx.x.xx2049
Mar 24 10:55:55 [serverName] stunnel: LOG5[6]: Service [efs] connected remote server from xx.xx.x.xx:51474
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe we talked about this on slack, but yeah if you start a corda node and it can't bind on the p2p port or p2pAddress. that could cause artemis errors like you're describing.

it might also be something strange going on in your network security group. Make sure you're able to get this working on your local machine and that the nodes can all ping / telnet each other on the ports that you expect.